# A word to describe a person who is easily identified by an article of clothing

Tags: single-word-requests

I had a classmate who always wore a pirate hat to school. Another, was frequently spotted riding a very large unicycle. Without the hat or unicycle, you would never notice the person otherwise. What is a term for a person who intentionally allows their identity to be reduced to one simple association?

Comment: The article or look or style is usually characterized as the person's *signature*, as in *signature [pirate] hat* or *signature style*. A prominent example is Leonard Cohen's song about a "famous blue raincoat". Note however this doesn't describe the *person*, so it isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps a ***conspicuous dresser***  although that does not cover a unicycle-  they’d still be *conspicuous* though; just not because of their dress.

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite what you are searching, i see not better.

**Eccentric**
 One that deviates markedly from an established norm, especially a person of odd or unconventional behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The type of phrase you are looking for reminds me of the Iliad, where Hector is sometimes called "great Hector of the shining helmet". Of course, calling someone "great Tom of the pirate hat", for example, would have a comical effect (possibly unintended).

Update: I forgot to mention the term **epitheton ornans** or **epithet**.

Answer (score -1):

**Iconic** is a good word in this situation, though it would usually describe the object, not the person.  "Here comes Fred on his *iconic* unicycle."  But the person himself could be referred to as **an icon**.